# Ubuntu 16.04 recognize external speakers as headphones

Tags: drivers, 16.04, sound, headphones, speakers

External speakers 2.1 are recognized as headphones, is it normal?

If not how can I fix it?

1. Notebook model: Dell Inspiron-3542
2. OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Pop-up after connect external speakers 2.1

[image]

Recognized as headphones

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Favour returned: You're a Rep 8 user already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal: if you already have speakers installed in your system in hardware, the second pair of speakers are recognized as "headphones" (as you very probably) plug them into the headphone port, not in the (internal) speaker port.

So unless you get your screw driver out and remove the internal speakers and hook up the external speakers to the internal port, *just ignore it*.

**;-)**

Comment: Yup, exactly right. Key point here is that the audio port ( for 3.5 mm jack ) doesn't have capability to distinguish devices, so it's safe to assume (from software point of view) that 99% of stuff connected through that port will be speakers.  If that was USB speakers then yes - USB bus has capability of determining the device type and "vendor" of the device.  Simple, but correct answer.